# Cannot connect ODBC to SQL 2008 on one PC

Tags: sql, windows-xp, odbc

I am trying to set up an ODBC connection to our SQL 2008 server.

So far i have set up 4 windows XP machines and 3 windows 7 machines.

However, the last XP machine isnt playing ball. I use all the same settings as i did on the other computers but i keep getting "SQL Server does not exist or access is denied".

Also, i cannot telnet to the SQL server on 1433. The windows firewall on the computer is OFF and there are no other security products.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you ping the server?

Comment: yes, by name and ip address. Its really very strange...